# How do I implement and execute threading with multiple classes in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, class, python-multithreading, python-class

I'm very new to Python (with most of my previous programming experience being in intermediate C++ and Java) and am trying to develop a script which will read sensor data and log it to a .csv file. To do this I created separate classes for the code-- one will read the sensor data and output it to the console, while the other is supposed to take that data and log it-- and combined them together into a master script containing each class. Separately, they work perfectly, but together only the sensorReader class functions. I am trying to get each class to run in its own thread, while passing the sensor data from the first class (sensorReader) to the second class (csvWriter) as well. I've posted some of my pseudocode below, but I'd be happy to clarify any questions with the actual source code if needed.

```
import time
import sensorStuff
import csv
import threading
import datetime


class sensorReader:

    # Initializers for the sensors.
    this.code(initializes the sensors)

    while True:

        try:
            this.code(prints the sensor data to the console)

        this.code(throws exceptions)

        this.code(waits 60 seconds)


class csvWriter:

    this.code(fetches the date and time)

    this.code(writes the headers for the excel sheet once)

    while True: 
        this.code(gets date and time)

        this.code(writes the time and one row of data to excel)

        this.code(writes a message to console then repeats every minute)


r = sensorReader()
t = threading.Thread(target = r, name = "Thread #1")
t.start()
t.join
w = csvWriter()
t = threading.Thread(target = w, name = "Thread #2")
t.start()
```

I realize the last part doesn't really make sense, but I'm really punching above my weight here, so I'm not even sure why only the first class works and not the second, let alone how to implement threading for multiple classes. I would really appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Thank you!

**EDIT**

I've decided to put up the full source code:

```
import time
import board
import busio
import adafruit_dps310
import adafruit_dht
import csv
import threading
import datetime
# import random


class sensorReader:

    # Initializers for the sensors.
    i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
    dps310 = adafruit_dps310.DPS310(i2c)
    dhtDevice = adafruit_dht.DHT22(board.D4)

    while True:

        # Print the values to the console.
        try:
            global pres
            pres = dps310.pressure
            print("Pressure = %.2f hPa"%pres)
            global temperature_c
            temperature_c = dhtDevice.temperature
            global temperature_f
            temperature_f = temperature_c * (9 / 5) + 32
            global humidity
            humidity = dhtDevice.humidity
            print("Temp: {:.1f} F / {:.1f} C \nHumidity: {}% "
                .format(temperature_f, temperature_c, humidity))
            print("")

        # Errors happen fairly often with DHT sensors, and will occasionally throw exceptions.
        except RuntimeError as error:
            print("n/a")
            print("")

        # Waits 60 seconds before repeating.
        time.sleep(10)


class csvWriter:

    # Fetches the date and time for future file naming and data logging operations.
    starttime=time.time()
    x = datetime.datetime.now()

    # Writes the header for the .csv file once.
    with open('Weather Log %s.csv' % x, 'w', newline='') as f:
        fieldnames = ['Time', 'Temperature (F)', 'Humidity (%)', 'Pressure (hPa)']
        thewriter = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        thewriter.writeheader()

    # Fetches the date and time.
    while True: 
        from datetime import datetime
        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

        # Writes incoming data to the .csv file.
        with open('Weather Log %s.csv', 'a', newline='') as f: 
            fieldnames = ['TIME', 'TEMP', 'HUMI', 'PRES'] 
            thewriter = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            thewriter.writerow({'TIME' : current_time, 'TEMP' : temperature_f, 'HUMI' : humidity, 'PRES' : pres})

        # Writes a message confirming the data's entry into the log, then sets a 60 second repeat cycle.
        print("New entry added.")
        time.sleep(10.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 10.0)) # Repeat every ten seconds.

r = sensorReader()
t = threading.Thread(target = r, name = "Thread #1")
t.start()
t.join
w = csvWriter()
t = threading.Thread(target = w, name = "Thread #2")
t.start()
```

Comment: Your classes contain no methods? All the behavior is in the initialization code? Why have classes at all?

Comment: Is the pseudo-code an accurate representation to your actual code? Because in that case, you seem to join the first thread before you even start the second.

Comment: I fear you've so heavily pseudocode-ized your classes that they're impossible to interpret. Can you show something a bit closer to real code, with perhaps only the external library calls abstracted? We can't really help you with the multithreading logic if the rest doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: @gilch Because so far, I've only gotten each task (reader/writer) to work with classes. After trying it with methods, it breaks. Besides, one of my professors who I showed this to for his input challenged me to add classes, and I don't like backing down from a learning curve.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Essentially yes, same order and hierarchy. In fact, I just copy-pasted the code and just changed it to the pseudocode without even touching the logic. Also, I tried using `join` because I thought that the cause may lie with the fact that it may not be progressing from `class sensorReader` to `class csvWriter` because the former is essentially in an infinite loop. So far, it hasn't worked.

Comment: @Blckknght I may have to do that. It calls a lot of external libraries and variables and I was afraid it may cause confusion. However, I'm planning on making this an open-source project (it's for a DIY internet-of-things weather station) and I've already plastered it on GitHub, so I don't see why not. I'll go ahead and edit it.

Answer (score 0):

It would work better structured like this. If you put the first loop in a function, you can delay its evaluation until you're ready to start the thread. But in a class body it would run immediately and you never get to the second definition.

```
def sensor_reader():
    # Initializers for the sensors.
    this.code(initializes the sensors)
    while True:
        try:
            this.code(prints the sensor data to the console)
        except:
            print()
        this.code(waits 60 seconds)


threading.Thread(target=sensor_reader, name="Thread #1", daemon=True).start()

this.code(fetches the date and time)
this.code(writes the headers for the excel sheet once)
while True: 
    this.code(gets date and time)
    this.code(writes the time and one row of data to excel)
    this.code(writes a message to console then repeats every minute)
```

I made it a daemon so it will stop when you terminate the program. Note also that we only needed to create one thread, since we already have the main thread.